# unable to deal with empty field in my code

Tags: javascript

Here I need to provide officename to find the address ,but one challenge which I am facing that if user does not type anything and hit search button then I want to acknowledge them to fill the req input.

I have implemented one function also that will get invocked when someone hits the search button.But I am unable to proceed for further execution.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please provide the code that you have preferably in a code snippet and what problems you have with your code.

Comment: @Alex_Angular on a serious note. You will get a lot better and more detailed answers if you put effort in describing your problem and show what you tried yourself. It's the best approach for learning too. You will learn a lot more from trying and failing yourself then just asking other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id =“officeInput” name=“officeiupit” size=“35”>
```

Point to critical input fields and save in global variables:

```
oOf=document.getElementById(‘officeInput’);
```

When a search button has been clicked, make a copy of the textbook content inside your function which you've made:

```
var sInputText=oOf.value;
```

In this case inside your function just put

```
if(!sInputText)
    alert(“You must enter an input.“);
```

Comment: @alex I think you are trying to implement Javascript Bible book problems.I request you to go through the basic concepts from this book before attempting any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like this:

`var searchText = document.getElementById('<ID_OF_INPUT_FIELD>').value;
 if(!searchText) {
    alert('Please enter something');
 }`